Solutions to this odd Diff Eq with an integral in it?
I’ve come to this unusual Diff Eq in a statistical physics problem.  A real positive density function $\rho\left(r,v\right)$ is a function of two real positive variables $0\leq r<\infty$ and $0\leq v<\infty$ and obeys
$$v\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial r}+\frac{C}{r^{2}}\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial v}\intop_{0}^{r}\intop_{0}^{\infty}\rho\left(r',v'\right)dv'dr'=0$$
where C is a real constant, $\rho\left(r,\infty\right)\rightarrow0$,  $\rho\left(\infty,v\right)\rightarrow0$, and $\intop_{0}^{\infty}\intop_{0}^{\infty}\rho\left(r,v\right)dvdr$ is positive and finite.
I’m pretty sure there’d be a family of functions that satisfy that condition.  I felt like I was making progress when I rearranged the equation so that one side was independent of v and dependent only on r:
$$\frac{v\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial r}}{\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial v}}=z\left(r\right)\equiv-\frac{C}{r^{2}}\intop_{0}^{r}\intop_{0}^{\infty}\rho\left(r',v'\right)dv'dr'$$
But that’s as far as I got.
So, what is the most general family of functions that satisfies this condition?   Thanks in advance.

What are the boundary conditions?

@Gonçalo  Thanks. I edited to add conditions.  Rho goes to zero as either variable goes to infinity. and the definite integral is finite.
